# Testing a condition on an expression throughout a range

Tags: expression, condition

How can one test a condition on an expression throughout a range?  My true expression is rather complicated, but consider this minimal example:

Is the function $2 - x^2$ positive throughout the range $0<x<1$?

I thought this might work:

```
Assuming[0<x<1,
Positive[2 - x^2]]
```

but it just returned `Positive[2 - x^2]` when the solution I seek is `True`.

The best I've been able to find is:

```
Simplify[Sign[2-x^2], 0<x<1]
```

which might suffice for simple functions, but doesn't for my complicated one (which involves hypergeometric functions).

My function is, incidentally:

```
1/2 y (Sqrt[(1+2 (-1+y) y)/(-1+y)^2]+(3-6 y) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2),1/4,5/4,-(y^2/(-1+y)^2)])
```

There are lots of ugly hacks, such as trying to `FindInstance` that the function is ever negative in that range, trying to `Solve` for the value being $0$, and so on, but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution.

The linked similar problems are very helpful (thanks @Nasser), but they do not work on my real problem:

```
Reduce[ForAll[y, 0 <= y <= 1 \[Implies] 1/2 y (Sqrt[(1+2 (-1+y) y)/(-1+y)^2]+(3-6 y) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2),1/4,5/4,-(y^2/(-1+y)^2)])> 0]]
```

Comment: `ClearAll[x]
f[x_] := 2 - x^2;
Reduce[ForAll[x, 0 < x < 1, f[x] > 0]]` gives True. see duplicate question where this is shown.

Comment: Thanks so much for the link, but alas, the linked solutions do not work with my complicated expression, so I'm still at a loss.

Comment: `f[y] = (1/
    2 y (Sqrt[(1 + 2 (-1 + y) y)/(-1 + y)^2] + (3 - 
        6 y) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 1/4, 
       5/4, -(y^2/(-1 + y)^2)])); Minimize[{f[y], 0 <= y <= 1}, y]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange):

```
FunctionRange[{2 - x^2, 0 < x < 1}, x, z]
```

> 1 < z < 2

For your more complicated example:

```
f = 1/2 y (Sqrt[(1+2 (-1+y) y)/(-1+y)^2]+(3-6 y) Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2),1/4,5/4,-(y^2/(-1+y)^2)]);

FunctionRange[{f, 0 < y < 1}, y, z]
```

> 0 < z < 1/8 (-4 + (9 Gamma[3/4])/Gamma[7/4])

Comment: Oh this is great.  I didn't know about `FunctionRange` but will be using it frequently from now on.  Thanks. ($\checkmark$)